# VS 2008 SP1/SQL SERVER 2008 SP1/TFS setup PROBLEM!

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, tfs, installation

I about to pull my hair out if i have to re install everything again!

I've installed Visual Studio 2008 SP1 then TFS and when I try to install SQL Server 2008 there is an error message telling me to install the SP1 of Visual Studio.

After a quick look on Google and SO, I've found the mysterious problem of TFS not being tagged as SP1 which is making the setup of SQLSERVER 2008 fail.

So I lost half of my day uninstalling everything and re installing all those Apps. Now my boss is asking me to do some analyses and reporting, BI,... that requires new plug in of SQL SERVER. You've guessed my problem: even after a good install VS SP1/SQL SERVER/ TFS the SP1 error is still remaining.

Does someone have a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finaly I've found a solution... Indeed installing TFS befor SQL Server 2008 (even a update) is aborting the setup of SQLSERVER so you have to uninstall **Microsoft Visual Studio 2008 Shell Integreted mode**, this is the component that is included in Visual Studio but not has SP1.

After updating my SQLServ adds in i juste re install the component.

Comment: That was a hell of a problem needed 3 full installs of VS2008, SQLSERVER, TFS to find out

Answer (score 1):

The root cause of your problem is that you're not patching your copy of Team Explorer up to SP1.  When you run the Team Explorer RTM installer on a system that already has Visual Studio SP1 you end up in a weird hybrid state that won't work correctly.

The correct solution is to either (a) install all VS components (including Team Explorer) before applying SP1 (b) if you find yourself in the 'hybrid' state, re-run SP1 and it will bring the remaining components up to date.